# git describe show only latest tag and additional commits

Tags: git, command-line, git-describe

Is there any syntax for [git describe](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe) to display only the latest tag and additional commits?

So that you get

`4.0.7` for being at the commit tagged `4.0.7`
`4.0.7-12` for having 12 commits since tag `4.0.7`

`git describe --tags` is pretty close with `4.0.7-12-g09181` but i haven't found a way to get rid of the hash being appended.

```
git describe --tags --abbrev=2
```

still displays `4.0.7-12-g0918`

```
git describe --tags --abbrev=0
```

displays `4.0.7` only.

Comment: There is no option in the describe command to do what you want. You could pipe the output to a shell script that removes the hash.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> There is no option in the describe command to do what you want. You could pipe the output to a shell script that removes the hash.

```
git describe --tags | sed 's/\(.*\)-.*/\1/'
```

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/32084572/1468708

thx !

Comment: Note that this will fail if the tag has a dash in it (e.g. `1.0.0-rc1`)

Answer (score 5):

I ran into a similar problem where I wanted to generate a string like: "tag-commits" but optionally followed with the -dirty and/or -broken suffix.

```
1.0-3    
1.0-3-dirty
1.0-3-dirty-broken
```

(Dirty simply indicates that you have uncommitted changes).

The accepted answer would however remove the -dirty (or when used -broken) tag at the end and leave the hash in the output.

To fix this I wrote the following command:

```
git describe --tags --dirty | sed 's/-g[a-z0-9]\{7\}//'
```

This works because the hash always starts with a "g" followed by 7 characters.

Comment: `a-f` instead of `a-z` and sometimes hashes are 9 characters long. So:
`git describe --tags --dirty | sed 's/-g[0-9a-f]\{7,9\}//'`